# Redux's Reducer - updating with keys as numbers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my current implementation, I have an initial state as so:

```
const state = {
  1: {id: 1, status: false},
  2: {id: 2, status: false}
}
```

I'm having a hard time how to implement the reducer correctly if I wanted to update the status on either the item.

I have the following as so:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TO_TRUE: {
      const { itemID } = action;
      let item = itemID.toString();
      return {
        ...state,
        item: {
          status: true
        }
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }

  }
}
```

Essentially I can't figure out how to pinpoint the right key. What's tricky is that the keys are setup as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a computed property key in the object literal definition:

```
return {
    ...state,
    [item]: {
      id: item,
      status: true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Allright, I need to go to sleep...and walk in shame

Answer (score 0):

You can access the item you want using bracket notation, which works as long as the key can be represented by a string. So for example:

```
const state = {
  1: {id: 1, status: false},
  2: {id: 2, status: false}
};

console.log(state['2']);
```

returns your second item.